# 8: Module Block Development

Tags: 8

I've been checking the examples for creating a custom module in Drupal 8 and found the [code](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/a-hello-world-custom-page-module) for the custom page module.

I was wondering if there is something similar but for modules that render custom blocks.

What I want to create is a custom module that makes a GET request to an API and prints the results in a custom block.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: The official docs are pretty straightforward on building a custom block in code as well as a module. What have you tried?

Comment: For the record, those official docs live here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-block. If it didn't work, or you got stuck, please ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Got confused on some of the concepts on the full page. Will check them out. Appreciate it.

Comment: You may also consider using Drupal console to generate the block custom code - it creates a great boilerplate you can customise. `drupal generate:module` if you need to create a custom module & then `drupal generate:plugin:block` for the block.